# Not able to upload a copy of file in folder

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file in a folder but not able to upload it. It is giving me error message.
Structure of file is: `c:/xampp/htdocs/uploadfile/uploadfile.php` and folder is `c:/xampp/htdocs/uploadfile/abc/`

Here is my code:

**uploadfile.php**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php">
    <input name="userfile" type="file" id="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Selected File" class="submit" />
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php

$allowed =  array('pdf','doc' ,'docx');
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
    echo 'There is an Error Occured while Uploading. <br><br>Please select right file type and try again.';
}
else {
    $uploaddir = '/abc/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    echo $uploadfile;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['name'], $uploaddir)) {
        echo "<br><br>File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Error Occured while uploading file. <br><br>Please try later.";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

Also try to change

`$uploaddir = '/abc/';`
to

`$uploaddir = 'abc/';` or  `$uploaddir ='./uploadfile/abc/';`

For more read manual :- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: @Divya then you need to accept/upvote helpful answers

Answer (score 1):

move_uploaded_file() function is not correct.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Check the folder name is exist and check the permission of that particular folder 

if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {
    echo 'There is an Error Occured while Uploading. <br><br>Please select right file type and try again.';
}
else {
    $uploaddir = 'abc/';
   // $uploadfile =  basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
   // echo $uploadfile;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['name'], $uploaddir)) {
        echo "<br><br>File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Error Occured while uploading file. <br><br>Please try later.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

`if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir)) {..}`

because PHP first checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a **valid upload file** (meaning that it was uploaded via `PHP's` `HTTP POST` upload mechanism and stored in temporary location).

If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination.

NOTE: However, restrictions are placed only on the destination path as to allow the moving of uploaded files in which filename may conflict with such restrictions. The `move_uploaded_file()` ensures the safety of this operation by allowing only those files, uploaded through PHP, to be **moved**.

**If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten.**

Also you can check whether the file was uploaded via `HTTP POST` with `is_uploaded_file()` function.

See details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php).